# Как удалить строки по условию с помощью метода drop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных, фильтрация

Не получается удалить строки по условию. Где ошибка?

```
data = data.drop(data[data['Комнат'] == 'Для заметок:'], axis=0, inplace=True)
data.head()

data = data.drop(data[data.columns[0] == 'Для заметок:'], axis=0, inplace=True)
data.head()

data = data(data[data.index['Для заметок:']], axis= 0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

**Общее замечание:** если вы используете параметр `inplace=True`, то `DataFrame.drop(...)` изменит фрейм на месте и **ничего не вернет**, что эквивалентно возвращению `None` в Python. Поэтому конструкция:

```
df = df.drop(..., inplace=True)
```

вернет `None` в `df`.

Советую вам не использовать параметр `inplace=True` вообще, т.к. [разработчики Pandas планируют от него отказаться в будущих версиях](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Лучше делать так:

```
df = df.method_name(...)
```

---

Альтернативные варианты решения вашей задачи (в порядке лучшей читабельности/производительности):

**Вариант 1:**

```
data = data.query("Комнат != 'Для заметок:'")
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
data = data.loc[data['Комнат'] != 'Для заметок:']
```

**Вариант 3:**

```
data = data.drop(data[data['Комнат'] == 'Для заметок:'].index)
```